# Change display text of AVPlayerViewController based on metadata

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller, avplayeritem

I am writing a basic Swift audio streaming application using `AVPlayer` and wanted to know if it was possible to change the default display text of the `AVPlayerViewController`. Currently the AVPlayerViewController looks like the following when I connect to the stream successfully:

[image: stream connected]

When the application is connected to the stream I am able to pull metadata using an observer on `AVPlayerItem.timedMetadata`. I want to know if I can override the default "Live Broadcast" text with a string, such as the metadata I am pulling. I know I could create a subview with a label and have the text displayed using `contentOverlayView?.addSubview`, but I think it would be cleaner if I could display the text directly in the `AVPlayerViewController` above the pause button.